# Magento removing item options in checkout order review section

Tags: magento

In my website i have enable one page checkout.Also there are only downloadable products.
I need to remove Item options in Checkout Order Review section (Please refer below image. I need to remove highlighted parts.)

[image]

Can anyone let me know how to do this please.

Thank You.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to remove custom option in checkout.

The custom options are displayed in the default template (in \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml) with the following snippet:

```
<?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
<dl class="item-options">
    <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
    <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
    <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
    <dd<?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
        <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
        <div class="truncated_full_value">
            <dl class="item-options">
                <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
<?php endif;?>
```

So, you comment this or remove as per your convenience.

But in your case you are using onepage checkout So, you have to check this code in extensions phtml file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But this didn't work for me. I checked all the files but nothing worked fine :(

Comment: can you please tell me which one-page checkout extension you are using So, that i can help you with exact code.

Comment: Default checkout. I enable it. System -> Configurations -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Options -> Enable Onepage Checkout = Yes

Comment: Please comment this below code.

<?php if ($links = $this->getLinks()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <dt><?php echo $this->getLinksTitle() ?></dt>
            <?php foreach ($links as $link): ?>
                <dd><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($link->getTitle()); ?></dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
<?php endif; ?>

from file app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\downloadable\checkout\onepage\review\item.phtml

and if you are using any theme you have to check this file in your theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go in `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\downloadable\checkout\onepage\review\item.phtml`

Open **item.phtml** file

And in this file here is code what is displaying that

```
<?php if ($links = $this->getLinks()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <dt><?php echo $this->getLinksTitle() ?></dt>
            <?php foreach ($links as $link): ?>
                <dd><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($link->getTitle()); ?></dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So you can remove or just comment this `<!--<dl>...</dl>-->` and you will get you want.

And yes go to `your theme folder` if your is not `rwd`.